# prioritize one query over the other in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Is it possible to prioritize one thread over the other in mysql. The scenario that I'm trying to address is as follows :-

2 threads T1 and T2 are both trying to acquire a lock on a table.

T1 is a batch-job, which if fails, can be restarted where as T2 is a normal request from an end user. Say T1 has acquired a lock on the table and at that point T2 comes in with a request. In such a scenario T1 should fail and allow T2 to acquire the lock.

Is it possible to achieve something similar in mysql or is there an alternative way to address such issue ?

Comment: So, if T1 asks for a lock first, shall it be allowed to set the lock or not? The whole requirements do not make much sense.

Comment: Update the question.   And put a ? mark in the question.

Comment: If t1 has a lock, it should release the lock if t2 comes knocking?  Should it rollback any changes it had made but not committed?  Hard to come up with an alternative design without more detail, but I'm pretty sure this design is not optimal.

Comment: @Thronk, Yes t1 should rollback all the uncommitted data. Assume the transactions for t1 to be small enough for the rollbacks to be not a big issue

Comment: But if the transaction for t1 is small then what is the big deal with just letting  the transaction finish.   A rollback could take as long as a commit and then t1 has to start over.    Have small transactions and small locks on T1.